# Where is the output resistance of M5 in the Output Resistance Expression

Tags: mosfet, analog, cmos, mixed-signal

Attached is the gain expression of the circuit
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's negligible so, it's excluded.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail, thanks.

Comment: The impedance at the drain of M5 is dominated by the sources of M1 and M2.